# How to map URL form ServletAction Class

Tags: java, servlets

We have 20 forms having action classes which has a suffix  `.jlc` eg, login.jlc, register.jlc, update.jlc etc. I want to know that while creating a single servlet class I have to explicitly write `.jlc` in servlet mapping for individual 20 files or I can use only *.jlc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use single mapping (*.jlc) only. See, for example, here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webapp/web_xml.html#wp1015060